# "element identification techniques" or "techniques of element identification"

Tags: nouns, formality

I don't know how this phenomenon is called. 
Simply put, I can either put the noun to the end and place it's properties before, or I can use "of". What is the difference, is some form more formal and suitable for academic writing?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. In some cases, in English even when both are acceptable one is more stylistically elegant. For example, the Strunk and White book on grammar is called The Elements of Style, but he could have called it: Style Elements. 
However, as a title it would not have been as elegant.

That said, when it is not a title and there is also an adjective, if used in the body of a text to identify some mode or technique, I see no problem with either one.

There really isn't a rule here. It's really a question of pleasing one's ear.